# Convert local database to cloud hosted mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, cloud

I have an application which is currently tied to the desktop application which will specific to each of my users.

1. The Existing application has about 300 table
2. The current database design is specific to a single user. For example , for a given clinic as user , we have following tables

• Patient
• Patient_address
• Patient_Images
• Employees
• Clinic_details
• Devices

3. What I want is to host this database on web. I want to use this database for multiple users and need to be able to store and retrieve data on a user unique key(Let’s say user ID)
4. The database will be local as well as cloud based i.e. I would like user to continue work even if they do not have internet, and be able to sync it on demand when connection is back, I may also choose to run a nightly sync process on user desktop.

What is the best strategy to do this? Currently I’m using MySQL, would it help if I switch to SQL?

Any help in this is appreciated.

Thanks
Bhim

P.S. - If this is not the right forum, please suggest the right forum for this question.

Comment: You're already using SQL, why switch? please don't be confused between the two, rather you want to switch to a different DMS (Database Management System) and the best strategy is to do it first, show us what you did if you find it wrong and let us see what we can help. We can't provide you the best possible solution by just hearing your thoughts

Comment: And one more thing, Try googling each of your question and get back here if you find it hard

Answer (score 0):

1. MySQL is SQL.  You cannot switch from MySQL to SQL.  It is like saying that you want to switch from Espresso to Coffee.
2. If you want the ability to work offline and sync when the connection is back, be prepared to be working on that little feature for the next couple of years or so.  I would say, do not even try.
3. For storing all of your "users" in one database, the term you are looking for is multi-tenancy, and it is a big subject, not suitable for a stackoverflow question and answer.  So, multi-tenancy is the term you want to google for in order to find information on how to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks You all for your response. I just want to make clear that when i said "would it help if I switch to SQL?" , i meant if Microsoft SQL has any inbuilt feature to support this.  As Mike suggested, going by "multi tenancy" helped. Thanks You all.